# Send "textarea" HTML message by email

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have tried to send the content of my "textarea" through email but this is sent blank. How to solve it?

My PHP code

```
<?php 
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
$ToEmail = "my-correo@hotmail.com"; 
$EmailSubject = "CONTACTO "; 
$mailheader="Fue enviado por: ".$input['nombre-contacto-2']."\n";
$mailheader .= "From: ".$input['email-contacto-2']."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$input['msn'];
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die 
("Failure"); 

echo "Saved";
```

My HTML code:

```
    <form action="" method="post" target="_blank" 
    onsubmit='event.preventDefault() ;sendForm1("form-contact")' 
     name="form-contact">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

  <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  
   placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="msn"></textarea>        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="send-1"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="send ">
        </form>
```

My JS code

```
   function sendForm1(formName){
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   http.open("POST","send.php",true);
   http.send(JSON.encodeForm(document.forms[formName]));
   http.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
     console.log(http.responseText);
     document.getElementById("send-1").innerHTML="<h1>sending</h1>";
     }
  }
}
     JSON.encodeForm = function(form){
     var array = {};
    for (key in form) {
    var item=form[key];
    if(form.hasOwnProperty(key) && item == "[object HTMLInputElement]"){
      array[item.name]=item.value;
     }
      }
     return JSON.stringify(array);
    }
```

The email that I receive is only blank content, what is happening?

Is the error due to textarea?

Comment: Why are you converting to JSON? XHR and PHP both speak `multipart/form-data`. And **don't trust user data in email headers.** And `"Fue enviado por: "` isn't a valid email header.

Comment: What is the correct way to send the form by mail?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change
$MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$_POST['msn'];
instead of
$MESSAGE_BODY.="MENSAJE".$input['msn'];

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your variables in an if statement so you can check if fields are actually filled eg.

```
 <?php

 if( isset($_POST['msn']){

  $msn = nl2br(addslashes($_POST['msn'])); //Remove invalid chars by using addslashes

  $ToEmail = "my-correo@hotmail.com"; 
  $headers = "From: $from\n";
  $msn =  "MENSAJE :". $msn;

  mail($toEmail, $headers, $msn) or die ("Failure");
```

Try to be consistent with naming variables to avoid mistakes and allow easy reading.

Docs about PHP addslashes: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php